# Amazon SQS long polling returning 0 messages when messages are in the Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Amazon SQS long polling is returning 0 messages when there are still messages in my queue. I've been able to reproduce this effect multiple times.

I'm aware that it's possible for SQS long polling to yield fewer messages than the max requested even if there are more messages on the queue.

I'm also aware that short polling can yield zero messages even when there are more than zero messages on the queue.

But I did not know that long polling could yield zero messages when there are more than zero messages on the queue. And from what I can tell after reading [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html), this isn't supposed to happen.

Question:

Is it possible for SQS long polling to return 0 messages even when there are messages on the queue? If so, are their specific conditions that make this likely to occur? If not, has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Comment: Your assertions are correct -- that should not be possible -- but the messages do have to be *visible* -- not already *in flight*.  Do you have messages showing in the console as in flight? Or as visible?  Is this a standard queue or a fifo?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sorry for the slow response here and thanks for the comment. No messages showing as in flight, everything is visible. And it's a fifo queue.

Comment: @PeterBerg I've just faced the same (I guess) problem - did you manage to solve yours?

Comment: @Pijotrek no unfortunately. I've resorted just polling once every 20 seconds all day long to make sure I eventually get all of my messages. I'm not happy about this solution =/

Comment: @PeterBerg thanks, I'll have to think of a work-around too

Comment: Can you post example code?

Answer (score 11):

Check that the group ID's are unique.

AFAIK, if one message in a group is in-flight, then the entire group is not visible.

Comment: When I add the messages I was using the same group id. It worked after changing group ids to different. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this could be related to any of these queue attributes:

- [Visibility timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html)
- [Delay queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html)

Please rewiew your queue configuration. Bear in mind that it's possible to set specific visibility timeout on a message level, which could not match the value set for the queue.

Hope this may help.

Best regards,